# how to collect map or reduce steps results for each workers in map-reduce processing?

Tags: mapreduce

I want to verify map and reduce steps results, so I need to know their results for each workers. but I don't know how to collect inputs and outputs per each workers (nodes).

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "word count");
    job.setJarByClass(WordCount.class);
    job.setMapperClass(TokenizerMapper.class);
    job.setCombinerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
    job.setReducerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
    System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
  }
```

Comment: Can you post any code you've written as well as what you've tried already?

Comment: ```.map``` and ```.reduce``` call the function passed on each element in your array.  Therefore whatever processing you need on a per element basis should be done in the functions passed to these methods.

Comment: Did you check the logs for each task?

Comment: For coding, I could not find exactly what components are appropriate and the code I get is not very relevant. I just run the typical examples such as the wordCount and I do not know where to get those values.

Comment: I want to review the results in the midst of the execution and verify their integrity.